# How to set name and value in s:doubleselect tag in Struts 2?

Tags: jsp, struts2

This is my code:

```
<s:set name="serverList" 
     value="#{
         'AppServer': {'Apache', 'Tomcat', 'JBoss'},
         'Database': {'Oracle', 'MySQL'}
         }" />
<s:doubleselect label="Server (OGNL) " 
name="server1" list="#serverList.keySet()" 
doubleName="server2" doubleList="#serverList[top]" />
```

Here how can I map the value Appserver to some key say 110 and correspondingly  {'Apache', 'Tomcat', 'JBoss'} to 1,2,3 respectively like it is done in select tag
 as in the code below Jan=1, Feb=2

```
<s:select label="Select a month" 
        headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select Month"
        list="#{'1':'Jan', '2':'Feb', '3':'Mar', '4':'Apr'}" 
        name="yourMonth" />
```

So that in my action class I can retrieve the values in my action class as 110 for Appserver, 1 for Apache and so on.

By default both select boxes appear one below the other is it possible to place them side by side?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: When I select a particular option like Apache I want to map it to a value of 110 which is available using select option as I have mentioned in the above question

Comment: By default both select boxes appear one below the other is it possible to place them side by side?
was a seperate additional question

Comment: So do you need this in `<s:doubleselect>` or `<s:select>`?

Comment: I need this in <s:doubleselect> not <s:select>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use map notation `#{...}` to create a map inside the list. And use `doubleListKey` and `doubleListValue` attributes of `<s:doubleselect>` tag with `key` and `value` keywords to get values from map.

```
<s:set name="serverList" 
     value="#{
         'AppServer': #{'11':'Apache', '12':'Tomcat', '13':'JBoss'},
         'Database': #{'21':'Oracle', '22':'MySQL'}
         }" />
<s:doubleselect label="Server (OGNL) "
name="server1" list="#serverList.keySet()" 
doubleName="server2" doubleList="#serverList[top]"
doubleListKey="key" doubleListValue="value"/>
```

In order to place select boxes side by side you need to change freemarker template for `<s:doubleselect>` tag.

**Update**

```
<s:set name="serverList" value="#{'101':'AppServer', '202':'Database'}" />
<s:set name="serverList2" 
     value="#{'101': #{'11':'Apache', '12':'Tomcat', '13':'JBoss'}, '202': #{'21':'Oracle', '22':'MySQL'}}" />

<s:doubleselect label="Server (OGNL) "
name="server1" list="#serverList.keys" listValue="#serverList[top]"
doubleName="server2" doubleList="#serverList2[top]" doubleListKey="key" 
doubleListValue="value"/>
```

Comment: But how do we set the value of AppServer in the action class for the first select box?

Comment: Hmm... perhaps by submitting the form?

Comment: You forgot to use `doubleListKey="key" doubleListValue="value"`.

Comment: What I want is when I select Apache after I submit the form I should get 110 in the action class

Comment: Sorry I meant  when I select Appserver in the first dropdown after I submit the form I should get 110 and secondly it displays 11=Apache, 12=Tomcat ,13=JBoss for the second dropdown instead of only Apache,Tomcat ,JBoss.

Comment: does it exist in struts 1? how can it be achieved?